# Extract the contents between two strings

Tags: regex

I have a single line of text I want to parse.

```
- Some text - some other text -
```

I want to fetch `Some text` and then `some other text` as two parts of the string.

So far I came up with the following regex

```
\- (.+?)(?= - )(.+?)(?= -)\
```

But this just returns the entire string without separating the two parts.

How do I change my regex to return the desired results?

Comment: What is your host language/RegEx implementation?

Comment: Does the language you're using happen to have a String.Split method? That would be simpler to use.

Comment: I'm using `NSRegularExpression` in Swift.

Comment: @stribizhev that's definitely a good solution too! Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
-\s*([^-]*?)\s*-\s*([^-]*?)\s*-
```

Explanation:

- `[^-]*?` capture all characters other than `-` in a non greedy way

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mH1wT4/5)

Comment: Thanks a million! You were so fast - I'll have to wait another 10 minutes before SO allows me to accept your answer :)

Comment: Also.. if you sure with spaces and dont want to capture them you can use `- ([^-]*?) - ([^-]*?) -`

Comment: check the above comment?? :D

Comment: My bad! It would be awesome if you updated your answer with it :)

Comment: Updated for more than one spaces (just in case) :)